# Flutter - Create Livestreaming Application that are shared realtime to Facebook and Youtube

Tags: flutter, live-streaming

I want to create a live streaming application but I don't know where to start.
I am using flutter and would like to know from you guys what do I need to consider when creating a livestreaming application?

Some questions:

1.) Is it possible to create livestream videos that will be directly (and in realtime) be shared to Facebook Live and Youtube Live while capturing it on the application?

2.) What about the comments in the application, as well as aggregating the comments from Facebook and Youtube, is it also possible get them all in the application?

3.) And all of this using flutter?

Thanks in advance, I am looking forward for your inputs.

Comment: Hey, have you got any solution? Are you able implement it?